# TFS 2017 nuget feed "Payment Required"

Tags: tfs, nuget

I have a TFS 2017 server set up with a Nuget feed for my local packages.  All of my developers have been using it without any issue.  However, I added a new developer today and he is not.  When he attempts to connect, he gets the error message "402 Payment Required."  He is set up with the same permissions and group memberships and my other developers and can access all other parts of the TFS server.  Any idea what would be going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At any point, you can have 5 users in your account using the 5 free Package Management licenses. You can check the items below:

1. Go to `http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_admin/_userHub` to make sure the user have assigned a Package Management license.
2. As users with a VS Enterprise subscription (`http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/_admin/_licenses`) automatically have access to Package Management, while users 6+ (that don't have VS Enterprise) need a license. You need to check whether other users have VS Enterprise subscription.
3. Clean TFS cache which usually locates in `%TfsData%ApplicationTier\_fileCache`.

Comment: You led me to the solution.  I couldn't get to the URL you provided above (substituting my own information into it), but using that, I was finally able to find where the Users are listed and add my new developer in.  All of the documentation is currently for VSTS which is just enough different from TFS 2017 that it was had me completely lost.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.feed):

> Get started with the first 5 users free! Additional users will need to
>   purchase Package Management to consume (i.e. nuget restore or npm
>   install) or produce (i.e. nuget push or npm publish) packages.

Comment: He's only my fourth user.

Comment: @DrewB At any point, you can have 5 users in your account using the 5 free Package Management licenses.